# Is this a recursion or not?

Tags: java, recursion, iteration

I have an argument with my friend because I don't think `fib_2()` is recursion, but he says it is because it calls itself.
I don't think it is because one `fib_2()` doesn't have a return result for use as an argument for another `fib_2()`.
I think `fib_2()` is the same with `fib_3()`,it's a iteration,not a recursion.

So is it a recursion or not ?

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("fib_1 -> %d\n", fib_1(10));
        System.out.printf("fib_2 -> %d\n", fff(10));
        System.out.printf("fib_3 -> %d\n", fib_3(10));
    }

    //This is recursion
    public static int fib_1(int n) {
        if (n == 1 || n == 2)
            return 1;
        return fib_1(n - 1) + fib_1(n - 2);
    }

    //Is this recursion or not ?
    public static int fff(int n) {
        int a = 1, b = 1, c = 0, count = 2;
        return fib_2(a, b, n, c, count);
    }

    public static int fib_2(int a, int b, int n, int c, int count) {
        if (count == n) {
            return c;
        }
        int tmp = b;
        b = a + b;
        a = tmp;
        c = b;
        ++count;
        return fib_2(a, b, n, c, count);
    }

    public static int fib_3(int n) {
        int a = 1, b = 1;

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            int temp = b;
            b = a + b;
            a = temp;
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fib_2 is recursive. fff is not.

The first call of fib_2 uses returns (hence 'uses') the result of the second call.

**Or formal:**

Recursion is defined by two properties:

1. A simple base case (or cases)—a terminating scenario that does not use recursion to produce an answer
2. A set of rules that reduce all other cases toward the base case

Your *if* inside fib_2 fulfills the first property.
The call to fib_2 fulfills the second.

---

*fib_3* is an iterative.

fib_2 is **not** equal to fib_3! 
Two functions are equal (in a mathematical manner), if and only if they produce the same output for every given input! fib_2 and fib_3 have different parameters so this can't be true.

`fib_3` may be equal to `fff` and/or `fib_1`

For equality in a computer science manner you have to consider things like side effects.

Comment: but it doesn't have a Backtracking

Comment: You are building a Stack of fib_2 calls. When you hit your base case (count == n) you walk the whole stack back by the returns.

Comment: @Saber The confusion happens, because you refer to both fib_2 functions as a single function, but they are not.

Answer (score 5):

`fff` is not recursive, because it does not calls itself. It calls `fib_2` which has a recursive implementation, but it is not enough to make the `fff` method recursive.

`fib_2`, on the other hand, is textbook-recursive: it has a base case for `count == n`, and it has a recursive branch that calls `fib_2` with new values of `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: but it does not have a Backtracking

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int fib_2(int a, int b, int n, int c, int count) {
        if (count == n) {
            return c;
        }
        int tmp = b;
        b = a + b;
        a = tmp;
        c = b;
        ++count;
        return fib_2(a, b, n, c, count);
    }
```

I think in this code recussion is happening.